# execute program from raspberry pi on remote windows PC

Tags: windows, apache, ssh, execute

I have Apache web server running on raspi. I need to execute a program on my PC (which is in the same network) from it. i.e. I click on button on webpage and it executes xyz.exe on my PC (windows 8.1).

What is a simple way to do it? Should I create some shell script that SSHs into my PC or is there another way?

Comment: you cannot start an application on your client from your browser - that if I understood correctly your problem. Theoretically if the apache server is configured to support `shell_exec` then you can run a script on your server that can ssh in your windows machine and do more.

Comment: Are you secretly asking how to infect a PC? :D This sounds like a very dangerous thing to do. The closest you can get to executing a binary is to run a Java applet.

Comment: Eugene Chow: Surely sounds littlebit like I'm trying to do that. But in reality, I have a dedicated game server and I want my friends to be able to run it with one click from the internet when I'm not at home